# Find a noncontinuous function $f: X \to Y$, where $U$ is open whenever $f(U)$ is open (satisfied non-vacuously.)

Tags: general-topology

Find a function $f:X \to Y$ that is **not** continuous, so that $U$ is open whenever $f(U)$ is open, where $X$ and $Y$ may not have the same topology .

I had a bit of a funny example, let $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (usual topology on the domain and codomain) be a step function, then for all open $U \subseteq \mathbb R$, we have that $f(U)$ is either a point, or two points, both of which are closed, so the function vacuously verifies the condition, but is not continuous.

Is there a more interesting example?

**incorrect** *remark:if $f$ is continuous, the condition is satisfied.*
Perhaps this is where the counter example is

Comment: Your remark is wrong.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo  how can that be so? if $V=f(U) \subseteq Y$ is open, and $f$ is continuous, then  $f^{-1}(V)$ must be open as well.

Comment: Because $f^{-1}(f(U))$ need not be $U$.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you

Comment: In general $U\subseteq f^{-1}(f(U))$

Comment: @KonKan I agree with that, with equality if bijective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $U$ is open in $X$ whenever $f[U]$ is open in $Y$, and let $V\subseteq Y$ be open. If $f\big[f^{-1}[V]\big]=V$, then $f^{-1}[V]$ is open in $X$. Thus, to get an example with a discontinuous $f$ we must ensure that there is an open $V\subseteq Y$ such that $f\big[f^{-1}[V]\big]\ne V$. It’s always true that $f\big[f^{-1}[V]\big]\subseteq V$, so we need to arrange matters so that $f\big[f^{-1}[V]\big]\subsetneqq V$. Clearly this requires that $f$ not map $X$ **onto** $Y$: we need to have $f[X]\subsetneqq Y$. Once you get this far, it’s not too hard to build an actual example.

Comment: Yes, I had precisely this problem with my first attempt, which was a $\tan(x)$, with the addition of two points that mapped to zero at $\pi/2,-\pi/2$. Thanks.

Comment: @Andres: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You could take $f: {\Bbb R} \rightarrow {\Bbb R}$ with 
$f(n)=n$, $n\in {\Bbb Z}$ and 
$f(n+t) = n+(1+t)/3$, $0<t<1$. It is continuous on each $(n,n+1)$ but discontinuous at every integer. If $f(U)$ is open it may not contain any integers so neither may $U=f^{-1}(f(U)\setminus {\Bbb Z})$.

Comment: I think this works. Could you alternatively take $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$, given by $f(x)=x$ for $x \in (0,1)$, $f(0)=1$, and $f(1)=0$? Seems like a similar idea.

Comment: @AndresMejia  It looks ok. If $f(U)$ is open, it may not contain neither $0$ nor $1$. So $U$ may not contain $0$ and $1$, either. And then $U$ is open.